# Override @RequestMapping in child Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

We use Spring 3.2 for our projects with a parent and child (maven) projects (child project extends the parent project).

We have an issue to override the `@RequestMapping` in the child project to redefine specifically the state of an URL. 
For example :

```
@Controller
public class MyParentProjectController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pdfRender")
    public ModelAndView pdfRender(MyParentProjectCommand command, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Application application)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And in the child project with a dependency on the parent project :

```
@Controller
public class MyChildProjectController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pdfRender")
    public ModelAndView pdfRender(MyChildProjectCommand command, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Application application)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Spring tells me it's impossible because there are two identical entry points in the child project. It's not possible to redefine a `RequestMapping`. I do not find a solution to do that without going through twisted stuff.
If you have a brilliant solution for me without use `@RequestMapping(value="${...}")`.

Best regards

Comment: try with: `public class MyChildProjectController extends MyParentProjectController`

Comment: How are they deployed?

Comment: @Javier Mollá : it's not possible. If I extend a controller, I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: If both projects are yours, I guess you could use a protected function inside the controller so you can override it when Child extends Parent

Comment: Duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751416/how-to-override-requestmapping-in-another-controller

Answer (score 0):

I'd make the parent an abstract class and leave that method unimplemented to override it.

If you want to have it that way, this workaround may help you; check out the SpringMVC router [project on GitHub](https://github.com/resthub/springmvc-router).

It's an implementation of [Play's Routes file](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0/routes) for SpringMVC.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. No weight or order possiblity ? I will see for this option, it requires reviewing many things (from our framework and projects)

Comment: Try to think if it's mandatory to have both parent and child service and if they could be two different.