# Override Spring Rest endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have 2 classes with same Request Mapping:

```
    @RequestMapping(path="home)
    class ParentController{

        @RequestMapping(value="index")
        public void home(){
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="home")     
    class ChildController{
        @RequestMapping(value="index")
        public void demo(){
        }
    }
```

The application fails because it has same request mapping.
But I want the ChildController to override ParentController.
Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `@Primary` or the conditional anotation you can use?

Comment: This does not make sense. Why would you want to override a HandlerMethod mapping?

Comment: 'over-think' of object orientation, are you trying to treat requestmapping like OOPS overriding? not a good idea.

Comment: The other commenters are correct.  Controllers do not override each other nor should they.

Comment: Look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751416/how-to-override-requestmapping-in-another-controller

Comment: In my case ParentController and ChildController are in separate projects. And ChildControllerProject has dependency on ParentControllerProject which has some base controllers. I need to override the base controller without making changes to the parentControllerProject and request are coming from the UI who's URL can't change. I guess the only solution I have seen that will work is to somehow add queryParam to the request made by ChildController which makes the request different.