# How to override @RestController bean in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, overriding, javabeans

I have a @RestController annotated class defined in a 3rd party .jar file in my springboot app. It's initialized via package scan. How can I overwrite this 3rd party controller bean with my own controller bean? Is there something like the "alias" of the xml configuration in spring-boot with java configure only environment?

Comment: creating a bean with the same name should, i believe, override the bean

Comment: have you tried `@Primary` over your `@RestController` ?

Comment: tried both, none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

Each mapping must be unique.There is no way to overrule an existing @RequestMapping.
There are workarounds for this though.
you can refer this post to get an idea about the answer :

[How to override @RequestMapping in another controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751416/how-to-override-requestmapping-in-another-controller)